# Mongo: Unknown group operator $toDouble

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to convert a string to a double using the `$toDouble` aggregate. However I am getting the error `"unknown group operator '$toDouble'`. Not sure why this is happening. Here's my query:

```
db.reviews.aggregate([{$unwind: "$Reviews"}, 
{$group: {_id: "$HotelInfo.Name", Price : {$toDouble: "$HotelInfo.Price"}}}, 
{$sort: {'Price' : -1}}])
```

And here is the document format: 
[Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChyqH.png)

Comment: What is your mongoDb version?

Comment: when using group, you can't use $toDouble in group. Because each group have many prices. You can use $sum in group

Comment: There are some `$group` [accumulators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#accumulator-operator) which only can be used inside the `$group` stage. `$toDouble` is not one of them.

Comment: Ok I see. The problem is that I am trying to sort on a value that is a string. How can I make it so that I can sort the price from greatest to least?

Comment: @treatyoself No there is no issue with the `$sort`. The error is with the `$group` stage. Try to explain what you are trying to achieve and use `@` to comment the specific person.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I am trying to sort the price of hotels from most expensive to least expensive. The problem is that I am sorting on a string number rather something that is a number.

Comment: As far as I can see from here. Your query is incorrect. So try to explain with some sample collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$toDouble` is supported in `mongodb` version 4 and above.

Hence update your `mongodb` version for it to work .